# Course Total Grade Custom Formula

Tags: moodle

In which part of Moodle Source Code, in which file can I find the Course Total Grade custom formula calculation???
I have searched the source code, but I cant find where the formula is defined
Thank you

Comment: This site isn't for asking these kinds of questions. You should read the asking a good question guide before posting. This is off topic first of all and you've provided no information on how anyone is supposed to help you, or what you've even tried.

Comment: I have a Moodle website and I want to change the way Course Total Grade is calculated. I am trying to find out where the Course Total Formula is stored. I was told by Moodle Support to ask the question here. Thank you

Comment: 1) Moodle support doesn't own/run/have any authority over this website 2) If their support department can't tell you something about their OWN software, then that's a huge issue.

Comment: Listen, my friend, I have no idea why you sound hostile to me, I am just trying to get help, I didnt offend anybody. Anyway thank you for not helping .....

Comment: It's not that I'm being hostile towards you, it's that this site isn't for the type of help you're asking about. There's other places that are more appropriate to ask a question like this. Literally did one google search with your issue: https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Grade_calculations and the answer is on their website. This is what I was trying to tell you before, questions like this are simple to answer and shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: I already did that, my friend, and I couldn't get exactly what i want. I am not stupid as you might think. The calculation formula does not solve my problem. Anyway thank you for your help, I ll try to use other ways to get what I want, thank you again

Comment: Well being as how you didn't even state exactly what you want, or the fact that you already looked there I'd say you should revise your question

Comment: I already posted a new question, trying to explain it differently, thank you